# Website links on home screen disappeared after device reboot

Tags: data-recovery, browser, motorola-moto-g, home-screen-shortcuts

I saved websites to my home screen on my phone. But for whatever reason, every time I update, it erases those websites that I save on my phone.
Earlier today, I restarted my phone. When I restarted it, this happened.

I need to save my websites there, as I can't remember them. But every time I try, they disappear.

How can I get them back? If it's relevant, it's a phone from Cricket Wireless.

Comment: Web site icons are additional links to the web browser you use to create them. They actually "belong" to the web browser. If you clear app data of the web browser this will erase also all saved web site icons. have you executed app data clear on the used web browser (I assume you use Chrome)?

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question is tagged with "Motorola Moto G". Just to make sure, is your phone Moto G? Just FYI, this site is only about Android OS, legal questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using my browser "bookmarks" to provide the easiest way to manage my links.
I have tried many different browsers bur I have to say the duck duck go browser does all I need.
I use it for this purpose in the following way.
When I brows the web sites and I want to have instant access later.
Open duck duck
Find your required web page.
Tap the top three dot menu.
Choose save bookmark.
(If a save to favourites) Pops up at the bottom of your screen then tap it.
If it doesn't then tap the three dot menu again and tap "bookmarks".
When the bookmarks list opens up you can tap the menu to the side of each bookmark and choose add to favourites (or remove from favourites). That's it.
Now everytime you open your browser the favourites you have set will all be showing as an instant link to your favourite pages.